# How to use EPPlus on webpage to generate and send Excel file to client?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, epplus

I'm trying to use [EEPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to generate Excel files on the server and send them to the clients browser. However, I don't know how to access the .net library from my .aspx page and use it.

I have copied the EPPlus.dll to the bin folder under my webpage and created the below test page. But when I run it, I get the following error:

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'ExcelPackage' is not defined. (l. 5)

I looked at the [example](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) on EPPplus webpage but it does not provide information about how to access the .net library.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**excel.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="OfficeOpenXml" %>

<%
Dim pck As new ExcelPackage()
Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo")

' Sheet's name
ws.Name = "Test"

' Set value for cell
ws.Cells["A1"].Value = 123

' Send to client
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx")
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
%>
```

Comment: You have the correct import statement. Are you sure you have the correct DLL's referenced? How did you install EPPlus? Are you using Visual Studio? Why aren't you using the code behind model?

Comment: Looks right to me. Maybe try deleting the reference and re adding it. If you want to be sure you have the right dll for epplus you could try and decompile it with http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Comment: I have only placed the EPPlus.dll in the bin folder of my website - other than that I haven't done anything. So you might be right that the dll is not correctly referenced. How do I fix that? An no, I'm not using Visual Studio -  the page is edited with notepad. And I don't know what the "code behind model" is.

Answer (score 0):

as this question still does not have an answer, here is what worked for me for an aspx solution that doesnt use codebehind...   i have the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll , EPPlus.dll and EPPlus.xml files in "bin" folder in the root dir and there are no other dll files in the bin folder. the solution itself does not have a compiled dll file either.

```
<%@ import Namespace="OfficeOpenXml" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="WebFormsTest.Models" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EPPlus" %>

<%    Dim pck As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage
    Dim ws As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet
    pck = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage

    ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Mailing List")
    ws.SetValue("A1", "a")

    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=MailingList.xlsx")
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
    Response.End
%>
```